# Adding wildcard response for a wildcard CNAME record

Tags: azure, dns, cname

I want to create a CNAME record `*.domain1.com` -> `*.domain2.com`
Basically, I want to reply by just changing the DNS suffix.

For example:
`abc.domain1.com` should resolve to `abc.domain2.com`
`pqr.domain1.com` should resolve to `pqr.domain2.com`
... and so on.

Problem is we **can not create a CNAME record with wild card in response**.
So is there any way to setup my DNS server to handle this, or is there any solution in Azure I can leverage?

To create DNS records I am currently using [Azure Dnszones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-zones-records#wildcard-records)

Comment: Can you tell me how you have created the DNS record for *.domain1.com ?

Comment: I am using azure dnszones https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-zones-records#wildcard-records

Comment: What you are searching far is the `DNAME` record that immediately "aliases" all names, one by one, no matter which. However support may be spotty, so you may get problems.

Comment: Also your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, and please do not obfuscate badly. You are using names that exist, and are not yours. You can use `example.com`, `example.net` and the full `.example` TLD for any documentation needs (but the DNS is public anyway so using the real names is always better).

Comment: Finally, any good DNS provider should be able to decorrelate the zone name from the zone content and hence should give you the feature of defining content on one side, and then applying it to one or more zones, which would immediately give the observed feature you need. Ask your DNS provider about that, and if it can't do it, maybe think about changing DNS providers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.  The DNS specification only allows a wildcard in label (left hand side of the mapping).

You can confirm this by by reading Sections 4.3.2 and 4.3.3 of https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt.

(And you can't create a CNAME for an entire domain; see https://serverfault.com/a/65792.)

---

I guess that you could handle this by using some automation to populate the entries for `domain1.com`; e.g.

```
for each <name> in domain2.com:
   add a CNAME <name>.domain1.com -> <name>.domain2.com
```

---

Or you could potentially do something like this with URL redirects; e.g.

1. Create a wild-card CNAME record

   *.domain1.com CNAME relay.domain2.com
2. Set up the `relay.domain2.com` webserver to redirect all `<name>.domain1.com` to `<name>.domain2.com` ... apart from `relay.domain1.com` case.

---

There may be other solutions.

Comment: Yes I am looking at other possible solutions.   

Relaying / redirecting traffic is something that would not work for me as I want to use the SSL certificate for `*.domain1.com`. If I relay or redirect traffic then I will also have to create an SSL certificate for `*.domain2.com` which I do not own.

Comment: You will have to anyway.  When the user's HTTP request that the sent to xyz.domain1.com ends up at xyz.domain2.com, the server is going to respond with a domain2.com cert.  If you didn't do a redirect, the browser will scream about the connection being insecure.  Or refuse it completely.

Comment: But If I add a cname record for `xyz.domain1.com` -> `xyz.domain2.com` then this isn't a problem. The SSL certificate for `*.domain1.com` will work in this case

Comment: I don't think so.  Not unless you have installed the `*.domain1.com` certs on the servers that run the `*.domain2.com` websites.   (Which you previously said that you don't own!)